# How do I solve it this error HTTP 400 - Unable to verify your data submission in Yii2?

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

My Yii 2 application was progressing well until I received an unusual error bout a bad HTTP request.

> HTTP 400 Unable to verify your data Submission.

I have looked it up and much of the literature indicates the cause being due to a `CSRF` issue. However, the `CSRF` components are all in place within the `HTML` head section and the hidden field is submitting the correct token.

**Additional Info**

> Yii version = 2.0.12 App Basic
>
> PHP version = 5.6
>
> OS = Ubuntu

I have disabled all the security firmware of the host but I still get the error. Please help the site is in Prod already and I can not find how to solve this many thanks in advance.

web/config/main.php

```
$config = [
'components' => [
    'session' => ['class' => 'yii\web\DbSession'],
    'request' => [
        'cookieValidationKey' => 'AAOSL2no3kbkJwRA4CNwDuB5g5T5_58t',
    ],
    'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
    ],
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    ],
    'errorHandler' => ['errorAction' => 'site/error'],
    'log' => [
        'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'db' => $db,

    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
        ],
    ],

],
'params' => $params,
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
$config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
$config['modules']['debug'] = [
    'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
    //'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1'],
];

$config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
$config['modules']['gii'] = [
    'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    //'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1'],
];
}
return $config;
```

Comment: first of all update your framework to the latest version which is not `2.0.12` but `2.0.14` and if it still persists then come back, use `composer update` via terminal inside your project root.

Comment: Do you use ActiveForm widget? If not you need to send token manually.

`<input id="form-token" type="hidden" name="<?=Yii::$app->request->csrfParam?>"
           value="<?=Yii::$app->request->csrfToken?>"/>`

Comment: Yes I am using the ActiveForm widget.

Comment: i see that you have enabled logging in your config what does the PHP error logs say? and do one thing, there will be `requirements.php` files inside the root of your application, copy it to `frontend/web` and then access it by `yourdomain.com/requirements.php`

Comment: did it fix for you or it still persists?

Comment: yes, luckily in the frontend of the site they do not realize pos, and I keep managing from my localhost because in the real host it keeps giving error 400

Answer (score 0):

As per [**`Change Logs`**](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/CHANGELOG.md), `BugFix` and `Enhancement` related to **`CSRF`** cookie.

### `2.0.13 November 03, 2017 updates include`

- **`Bug #14542`**: Ensured only ASCII characters are in CSRF cookie value since binary data causes issues with ModSecurity and some browsers (samdark)
- **`Enh #14087`**: Added **`yii\web\View::registerCsrfMetaTags()`** method that registers CSRF tags dynamically ensuring that caching doesn't interfere (RobinKamps).

### `2.0.14 February 18, 2018 updates include`

- **`Bug #15317`**: Regenerate `CSRF` token if an empty value is given
- **`Enh #15496`**: (CVE-2018-6009): `CSRF` token is now regenerated on changing identity (samdark, rhertogh)(sammousa)

So update your framework to the latest version `2.0.14` use `composer update` via terminal inside your project root, once updated make sure you have the

```
 <?= Html::csrfMetaTags () ?>
```

inside the `<head>` tag of the `layout` file you are using either `main.php` or any other custom name.

If still persist you can disable it for the specific action inside the `beforeAction`

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{            
    if ($action->id == 'action-name') {
        $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    }

    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

or for a specific controller by adding

```
public $enableCsrfValidation = false;
```

Comment: I have updated to the latest version and the error persists, I have the "<?= Html::csrfMetaTags () ?>" in the layout, and deactivating the Csrf protection in the forms is not an option for me. This stop of crazy this error does not make any sense.

Comment: umm english please ?

Comment: Sorry yes. It is in English now.

Comment: is it happening with all the forms on your app,

Comment: Yes with all the forms, if you need more information to help me just ask me.

Comment: The error started to occur from a server migration, I first thought it could be some security firmware, but now I'm running it on a server that is totally clean and totally exposed, zero firmware and the error persists.

Comment: I have read in several places that this error has happened to others but nobody comes up with the answer to solve it.

Comment: can you share your `frontend/config.php` and after updating framework do clear cache and remove cookies or try incognito mode with chrome

Comment: There is this my configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>` in your view, or add in layout(main.php)